Graphviz renderer/explorer for large graphs?
I have a .dot file with an enormous directed graph and need to explore it visually.
I have tried Gephi but it fails to render the file. Browser based renderers freeze my browser.
It would be awesome to have the ability to collapse/expand nodes, zoom and explore. Graph comparison would also be amazing.
Does any such tool exist?

Define enormous - how many nodes & how many edges?  Use gc to get these numbers.  Then use ccomps -vs to determine the number of disconnected components.

It's ~500k nodes and ~2mil edges (might not be gigantic gigantic) - though my M1 MBP struggles with 1/5rd of that with Gephi. The animations don't help and I haven't found a way to turn them off

Indeed, enormous.   You might also ask this question at the Graphviz forum (https://forum.graphviz.org/).

Is the data hierarchical? If it is, you could build a custom app that still uses Graphviz to build a graph where the hierarchical groups are initially collapsed, and then allow exploration of the graph by expanding nodes.
I just built something like this to visually explore the symbols in software code (variables, functions, classes, etc).
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AtomicConcepts.atomicviz
